# Session and view scoped beans - Values being overwritten

Tags: jsf-2

```
@SessionScoped
public SessionClass{

    // Buyer is a view scoped class
    private List<Buyer> sessionObject = new ArrayList<Buyer>();
}
```

When updating a input field buyer.fname. The list is also updated.
Should I change the Buyer class to session scope also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with JSF scopes, but everything with the object oriented nature of Java. Apparently the view scoped `Buyer` instance represents exactly the same **reference** as the item in the list of the session scoped bean (it's however beyond me how you coded it like that; it would have been explainable if `Buyer` is actually a JPA entity).

You should be creating a copy of the `Buyer` instance instead or detach the entity if it's indeed a JPA entity.